# Submitting a .cshtml form only when all conditions are met

Tags: javascript, c#, html, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with in .net core razor pages. I making a form in *.cshtml* file I have implemented form validations on input elements using javascript. On submit of the form I am calling a *validate()* function which checks if all validations return true and I want my form not to submit if any of the validation returns false.

Post request is being made through .cshtml.cs file, here is my .cshtml code:

```
@page
@model Sora.UI.Pages.SignUpModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SignUp";
    //string errorMessage = ViewData["UIErrorMessage"].ToString();
}
@*var coun=0;

<section class="py-0" id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row flex-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-xl-5 pe-xxl-0">
                <div class="card card-bg hero-header-form">
                    <div class="card-body p-4 p-xl-6">
                        <h2 class="text-100 text-center">New User Sign Up</h2>
                        <form class="mb-3" method="post">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="l1">
                            <input  onchange="fname()" class="form-control input-box form-ensurance-header-control" name="signUp.FirstName" id="signUpFirstName" type="text" placeholder="FirstName" />
                            <label for="signUpFirstName">First Name</label>
                              <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="l2">
                            <input onchange="lname()" class="form-control input-box form-ensurance-header-control" name="signUp.LastName" id="signUpLastName" type="text" placeholder="LastName" />
                            <label for="signUpLastName">Last Name</label>
                              <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="l3">                  
                            <select onchange="checkcountry()" class="form-control form-ensurance-header-control" id="signUpCountryCode" asp-for="signUp.CountryCode" placeholder="Country" asp-items="Model.signUp.CountryList">
                                <option selected></option>
                            </select>
                            <label for="signUpCountryCode">Country</label>
                              <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="i4">
                            <input onchange="checkMobile()" class="form-control input-box form-ensurance-header-control" name="signUp.MobileNumber" id="signUpMobileNumber" type="tel" placeholder="9876543210"  />
                            <label for="signUpMobileNumber">Mobile</label>
                            <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="i5">
                            <input onchange="checkEmail()" class="form-control input-box form-ensurance-header-control" name="signUp.Email" id="signUpEmail" type="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" />
                            <label for="signUpEmail">User Name (Email Id)</label>
                            <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="i6">
                            <input onchange="checkpass1()" class="form-control input-box form-ensurance-header-control" name="signUp.Password" id="signUpPassword" type="password" placeholder="password" />
                            <label for="signUpPassword">Password</label>
                            <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="i7">
                            <input onchange="checkpass2()" class="form-control input-box form-ensurance-header-control" name="signUp.ConfirmPassword" id="signUpConfirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="confirmpassword" />
                            <label for="signUpConfirmPassword">Confirm Passwod</label>
                            <span ></span>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-12 d-grid">
                            <button onclick="validate()"  class="btn btn-primary  rounded-pill"  type="submit" id="submitButton">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var count=0;
        const fname=()=>{
             const a=document.getElementById("signUpFirstName").value;
            const new1= document.getElementById("l1");
             const new2=new1.getElementsByTagName("span");
             const b=document.getElementById("signUpFirstName").name;
             console.log(b);
             if(a.length===0)
             {
                 
                 new2[0].innerHTML="Please Enter Your First Name";
                new2[0].style.color="red";
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                 new2[0].innerHTML="";
                 return false;
             }
        }
         const lname=()=>{
             const a=document.getElementById("signUpLastName").value;
            const new1= document.getElementById("l2");
             const new2=new1.getElementsByTagName("span");
             if(a.length==0)
             {
                 new2[0].innerHTML="Please Enter Your Last Name";
                new2[0].style.color="red";
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                 new2[0].innerHTML="";
                 return false;
             }
        }
         const checkcountry=()=>{
             const a=document.getElementById("signUpCountryCode").value;
            const new1= document.getElementById("l3");
             const new2=new1.getElementsByTagName("span");
             if(a.length==0)
             {
                 new2[0].innerHTML="Please Enter Your Country";
                new2[0].style.color="red";
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                 new2[0].innerHTML="";
                 return false;
             }
        }
        const checkMobile=()=>{
            const a=document.getElementById("signUpMobileNumber").value;
             const new1= document.getElementById("i4")
             const new2=new1.getElementsByTagName("span");
              const phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
               console.log(a.length);
            if(!(a.match(phoneno)))
            {
               new2[0].innerHTML="Please Enter a valid Mobile No.";
                new2[0].style.color="red";  
                count=1;
                return true;
            } 
             else
            {
                new2[0].innerHTML="";
                count=0;
                return false;
            }

        }
       const checkEmail=()=>{
            const a=document.getElementById("signUpEmail").value;
            var mailformat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
            const new1= document.getElementById("i5")
             const new2=new1.getElementsByTagName("span");
            if(!a.match(mailformat))
            {
                console.log("ui")
                 new2[0].innerHTML="Please Enter a valid Email id.";
                new2[0].style.color="red"; 
                count=1;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                new2[0].innerHTML="";
                count=0;
                return false;
            }
           
       }
       const checkpass1=()=>{
           const a=document.getElementById("signUpPassword").value;
            const new1= document.getElementById("i6")
             const new2=new1.getElementsByTagName("span");
             const specialChars = /[`!@@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
           if(a.length<8)
           {
                new2[0].innerHTML="Password length must be atleast 8 characters";
                new2[0].style.color="red"; 
                count=1;
                console.log("count",count);
                return false;
           }
           else if(a.length>12)
           {
               new2[0].innerHTML="Password length must not exceed 12 characters";
                new2[0].style.color="red";  
                count=1;
                return false;
           }
           else if(!specialChars.test(a))
           {
               new2[0].innerHTML="Password must contain atleast 1 special character";
                new2[0].style.color="red"; 
                count=1;
                return false;
           }
           else{
                new2[0].innerHTML="";
                count=0;
                 console.log("count",count);
                 return true;
           }
           
       }
       const checkpass2=()=>{
            const a=document.getElementById("signUpConfirmPassword").value;
              const b=document.getElementById("signUpPassword").value;
            const new1= document.getElementById("i7")
             const new2=new1.getElementsByTagName("span");
             if(a!=b)
             {
                 new2[0].innerHTML="Password does not match";
                new2[0].style.color="red"; 
                count=1;
                return false;
             }
             else
             {
                  new2[0].innerHTML="";
                  count=0;
                  return true;
             }
       }
       
             
    const validate=()=>{
          if(!(fname() && lname() && checkMobile() && checkcountry() && checkEmail() && checkpass2() && checkpass1() ))
          {
              console.log("error, don't submit form!!");
            //document.getElementById("submitButton").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
          }
               console.log("alight go ahead.");
      }
    </script>
</section>
```

below is my .cshtml.cs code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

using Sora.Infra.DTO.Common;
using Sora.Infra.DTO.User;
using Sora.UI.CacheManager;
using Sora.UI.ViewModels.SignUp;
using Sora.UI.WebAPIConsumer;

namespace Sora.UI.Pages
{
    public class SignUpModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public SignUpPageVM? signUp { get; set; }

       // private readonly IHttpClientFactory? _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IConfiguration? _configuration;

        private readonly IWebAPIClient<UserSignUpRequestDTO,BaseResponseDTO>? _webClient;
        private readonly IWebAPIClient<string, List<MasterDataContent>>? _masterData;

        private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;



        public SignUpModel(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,IConfiguration configuration, IWebAPIClient<UserSignUpRequestDTO, BaseResponseDTO>? webClient,IWebAPIClient<string,List<MasterDataContent>> masterData, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
           // this._httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            this._configuration = configuration;
            this._webClient = webClient;
            this._masterData = masterData;
            this._memoryCache = memoryCache;
           
            this.signUp = new SignUpPageVM();
            
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue("CountryList", out List<MasterDataContent> cacheValue))
            {
                var countryList = await this._masterData.GetData("MasterDataItems/GetCountry", "");
                cacheValue = countryList;               
                _memoryCache.Set("CountryList", cacheValue,SoraCacheManager.ThreeHunderedSecondsCache());
            }

            signUp!.CountryList = new SelectList(cacheValue, "key", "value");

            return Page();
        }

        //public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()

        //public  IActionResult OnPost()
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if (signUp.ConfirmPassword != signUp.Password)
            {
                ViewData["confirmation"] = $"Password does not match";
                return Page();
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
          
            UserSignUpRequestDTO signUpRequest = new UserSignUpRequestDTO();
            signUpRequest.FirstName = signUp?.FirstName;
            signUpRequest.LastName = signUp?.LastName;
            signUpRequest.MobileNumber = signUp?.MobileNumber;
            signUpRequest.Email = signUp?.Email;
            signUpRequest.CountryCode = signUp?.CountryCode;
            signUpRequest.Password = signUp?.Password;

            var response = await this._webClient!.PostData("User/SignUp", signUpRequest);

            return RedirectToPage("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me fixing this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `$().submit()` to submit the form.

1.add id to the form:

```
<form id="myForm" class="mb-3" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

2.submit the form if all validations return true:

```
const validate=()=>{
          if(!(fname() && lname() && checkMobile() && checkcountry() && checkEmail() && checkpass2() && checkpass1() ))
          {
              console.log("error, don't submit form!!");
            //document.getElementById("submitButton").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
          }
               console.log("alight go ahead.");
               $("#myForm").submit();
      }
```